# Is calling methods on Activity in Fragment's onDestroy method safe?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an `Activity` `MyActivity` and a `Fragment` `MyFragment`. The `Activity`'s `onDestroy()` method starts with `super.onDestroy()`.

From log statements and also a bit from looking at the `Android` source code, it looks like the `Activity`'s super `onDestroy()` method calls the `Fragment`'s `onDestroy()` method. Then when the `Fragment`'s `onDestroy()` method is finished the rest of the `Activity`'s `onDestroy()` method is executed. So I believe, the `Activity` isn't destroyed until after the `Fragment`'s `onDestroy()` method is finished.

This makes me think that from `MyFragment`'s `onDestroy()` method I can safely call quick methods on `MyActivity` and rely on `MyActivity`'s attributes. I would never do that, but hypothetically, could I rely on attributes and methods in `MyActivity when I'm in MyFragment's onDestroy method?

The documentation's description of `Activity`'s `onDestroy()` method, *"The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed"*, I take to mean AFTER this method returns the `Activity` will be destroyed.

The `Fragment`'s `onDestroy()` method documentation doesn't really say whether the `Activity` has started the destroy process.

Comment: Using the `Activity` on `onDestroy()` is completely safe. After `onDestroy()` another lifecycle method called `onDetach()` is called and only from them on its the `Activity` not save to use. After that `getActivity()` or should return null until `onAttach()` is called again. `onAttach()` is one of the first calls in the `Fragment` lifecycle and happens before `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely safe to use the hosting `Activity` in the `onDestroy()` method of your `Fragment`.
A simplified version of the `Fragment` lifecycle looks like this:

- `onAttach(Context)`: The Fragment is attached to a host (usually an `Activity`)
- `onCreate(Bundle)`
- `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)`
- `onStart()`
- `onResume()`
  ...
- `onPause()`
- `onStop()`
- `onDestroyView()`
- `onDestroy()`
- `onDetach()`: The `Fragment` is detached from its host.

So for the whole lifecycle from `onCreate(Bundle)` to `onDestroy()` you can use and refer to the hosting `Activity` without any problems.

Comment: Ok, although, by me, the comment in question seems to be more helpful regarding to what the OP asks :)))

Comment: @Onik, sorry I don't know what OP means?

Comment: @flobacca [What does OP mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean)

Comment: I'm going to use two comments to answer, so please read both comments. I don't think it is completely safe to use the activity in the fragment's onDestroy call. The reason is that the Activity's performDestroy() method calls mWindow.destroy() before calling mFragments.dispatchDestroy(). So the activity is not totally intact when the fragments are destroyed. Also in the future who knows what methods will be called before Activity's mFragments.dispatchDestroy() method. So in the future the Activity may be more destroyed before calling the fragment's onDestroy method.

Comment: However, it is probably safe to use attributes and methods from MyActivity in MyActivity's onDestroy method because onDestroy's super method won't change attributes belonging to MyActivity. Also, Activity calls mFragments.dispatchDestroy() before calling onDestroy(), so it looks like Activity is taking measures to destroy its fragments before destroying itself. Similar arguments can be made for AppCompatActivity as its super.onDestroy method is commented as 'Destroy all fragments and loaders'. Continued on next comment.

Comment: So in the end, I think it's not safe to use the Activity in Fragment's onDestroy method, but with caution it's okay.

Comment: Lastly, I don't think we can really tell if the Fragment's onXXX methods are called before the Activity's corresponding lifecycle methods just by looking at their lifecycle charts. In the MyActivity's and MyFragment's lifecycle methods, I first call their super methods, then I call a log statement. In onResume the Activity's log statement is called first, then the Fragment's log statement. However, in onPause the Fragment's onPause method is called first. So, even though I could agree with you that using the Activity's attributes is safe, I can't agree to your reasoning.

Answer (score -1):

It's not safe to rely on onDestroy(), check [table](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Activity can be killed after onPause().

As a Fragment mirrors lifecycle of the host Activity, it will be killed as well.

> but hypothetically

Well, `onDestroy()` should be called before the host Activity.

Also you may check [complete Android Fragment & Activity Lifecycle](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle).

Take into account new permissions handler in api 23. User may revoke permissions at runtime and your process will be terminated same way as "low memory situation".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you referring to the "In general the movement through an activity's lifecycle looks like this:" chart? That's referring to the Activity's onDestroy() method.  I agree the Activity can be killed after pause, but my question is in the Fragment's onDestroy method, so the case I'm asking about is when the Activity's onDestroy method is called.

Comment: As a Fragment mirrors lifecycle of the host Activity, it will be killed as well.

Comment: you are misinterpreting the chart. All components whether it be `Activity` or `Fragment` will always go through their full lifecycle. There is no way that an `Activity` can just be killed after `onPause()` without also calling `onStop()`,  `onDestroy()` and all the other lifecycle methods.

Comment: And a `Fragment` will just as well go through its while lifecycle. `onDestroy()` is before `onDetach()` on the lifecycle of the `Fragment` so using the `Activity` on `onDestroy()` is completely safe.

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller The statement _"All components whether it be Activity or Fragment will always go through their full lifecycle. There is no way that an Activity can just be killed after onPause() without also calling onStop(), onDestroy() and all the other lifecycle methods"_  isn't correct. `onStop()` and especially `onDestroy()` may not be called when the system is low on memory. By the reason, `onSaveInstanceState()` is called at some place between the calls to `onPause()` and `onStop()`.

Comment: @Onik You got that half right. The only way that `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` are not called is when the whole process is killed. In other words that only happens when your whole app dies and then there could be no part of your app left that could care if another component has gone through its whole lifecycle or not. And that applies to anything in your app not just `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`.  A process can be killed at any time regardless of what state your app is in.

Comment: @Onik However as long as your app keeps running you can absolutely be sure that every component adheres to its lifecycle. Otherwise there would be no point to having a lifecycle in the first place.

Comment: What I meant is that onDestroy may never be called, so this is the bad way to organize code.

Comment: And I am saying that `onDestroy()` is always called. If it isn't called than your whole app was killed and than if doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @XaverKapeller to free some resources is fine, because it will be wiped anyway with process, but so save smth...

Comment: @MaximG You can depend on all the lifecycle methods to always be called. That's the point of having a lifecycle. You shouldn't optimize for corner cases. If any lifecycle methods are not called than something has gone very wrong. It's Androids responsibility to control all this and if it decides not call a lifecycle method you should not try to work around that. That's an easy way to introduce bugs and weird behavior. To summarize: Trust Android to do what's right and trust the lifecycle methods to be called when they are necessary to be called.

Comment: I trust and documentation points that Activity can be killed after onPause(). I guess it's rear on new devices with stock Android. But custom versions may trigger optimization even when the system is not really on low memory.

Comment: @MaximG No, an `Activity` cannot just be killed and disappear without going through the whole lifecycle. You are misinterpreting the chart on the Android Developer page. The only thing that can happen is that the whole app is killed, and you don't need to worry about that. Whatever optimizations a device may or may not apply does not matter. You can trust that any component will always adhere to its lifecycle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112692/discussion-between-maxim-g-and-xaver-kapeller).